# Replace object Index in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, object, replace, nsmutablearray

I have `NSMutableArray`. There are for example such objects: 0, 1, 2.
How can I replace object `0` into index where object `2`. In result I want array with objects: 1, 2, 0. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@trojanfoe, there is a simple mistake in your answer.

The first line of the code does not return anything as per doc. So it should be,

```
id object = [[array objectAtIndex:0] retain];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[array insertObject:object atIndex:2];
[object release];
```

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: There is no need to retain and later release `object` because `objectAtIndex` returns a retained and autoreleased object.

Answer (score 0):

```
[array addObject:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

First get a copy of the object, then remove it from index 0, then add it at index 2.

```
id object = [array objectAtIndex:0];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[[array insertObject:object atIndex:2];
```